# Setting vue.js watchers within for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Experimenting with adding watchers dynamically in Vue.js. Disconnect between desired/actual results is shown in the commented portion below. Occasional/amateur coder here; I suspect my problem is less with Vue and more with understanding of JavaScript fundamentals. Thanks in advance!

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: 3
    },
    methods: {
        setUpWatchers(array) {
            for (var i in array) {
                var key = array[i];

                this.$watch(key, function(newValue) {
                    console.log(key + ': ' + newValue);

                    //desired output is:
                    //  a: 4
                    //  b: 5
                    //  c: 6

                    //actual output is:
                    //  c: 4
                    //  c: 5
                    //  c: 6

                });
            }
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.setUpWatchers(['a', 'b', 'c']);

        this.a = 4;
        this.b = 5;
        this.c = 6;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, this is a classic javascript "gotcha".

Variables declared with `var` have a function scope. When using `var` *all* of the functions declared in your loop (you are declaring 3; the handlers for $watch) are using the `same` variable, which, after the loop is complete, points to `c`.

A quick fix is to declare your variables with `let`. `let` has block scope, so each function declared in your loop will have access to just the copy of the variable as it existed at the time the function was created.

Here is a working example.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: 3
    },
    methods: {
        setUpWatchers(array) {
            for (let i in array) {
                let key = array[i];

                this.$watch(key, function(newValue) {
                    console.log(key + ': ' + newValue);
                });
            }
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.setUpWatchers(['a', 'b', 'c']);

        this.a = 4;
        this.b = 5;
        this.c = 6;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Ideally, these days, you should be using `let` or `const` and almost never `var`. There are numerous resources that are available that will describe the differences.

Comment: Thanks much @Bert. Indeed, I was vaguely aware that `let` and `const` were the New Thing, but hadn't looked into them yet because `var` was "working" for me.

Comment: @wwninja A lot of cases it doesn't matter; this just happens to be one where it does :) The fix was more involved before `let` was available (it involved creating a closure in each iteration of the loop).